# How can set version to gRPC API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, versioning, grpc

I`m setup a new gRPC API using c# and asp.net, the problem is that i cant set version to api, something like

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
```

tag in REST API`s.
can anyone help me about this?